# Interlude for a melody composed between chorus ad verse for 30 second without vocal

Tags: songwriting

Need tips for the instruments to be arranged & played for a song when there is a break for vocal between the song moving from chorus to verse or verse to chorus.Already planned for accompaniment with acoustic guitar,snare Drum,Keyboard,Electric guitar and shaker for the intro,verse & Chorus.But not getting idea how to fill the gap in Interlude in-between chorus & verse.The song structure is Intro ,Verse 1 + Interlude 1 + Chorus 1,Verse 2 + Interlude 2 + Chorus 2,Outro,End.

Comment: Need more information - type of song, tempo, feel,  length of verses/choruses, where the chorus goes in comparison to the verse, major or minor, all of which would have a bearing on suggested interludes.

Comment: Type of song- Indian Gospel,Tempo-95,Feel-Slow breezy movement,Verse -12 bar,Chorus-18 bar,Key- E major ,3/4 rhythm.The song will move from intro to verse and then chorus - i want a instrumental Interlude between this.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by considering the point of the interlude. What's it doing in your song? What is it's function, or purpose? What would the song lose if you missed it?

Once you've decided what it does, you can think about how to arrange it.

Let's assume that your interlude is aiming to build energy and anticipation, that is met by the chorus when it finally arrives. You're going to want a chord progression that builds tension, and guides the listener towards the release of the chorus. Perhaps add a melodic line, or a hook, or a riff. Something to grab attention, and say "listen up, the boring verse thing is over, you know the words to the next bit, prepare to sing along!" (note: perhaps this is an overly cynical view of your average modern pop song).

You could also change up your instrumentation.  What if the verses were driven by the keyboard, and the guitars waited until the interlude to sneak in, and build up to a big chorus? Or, the opposite. Simple acoustic guitar, with the keys bringing it all together for your big moment.

Of course, my assumption could be very wrong. Perhaps you want your listener to think about what you've said in the verse, and contemplate it, before moving to the next idea. You could repeat the melody instrumentally, with some variation. Sometimes less is better, and some simple chords is all it needs.

It all depends on what you're trying to do with this interlude. Perhaps the song is stronger without it? Once you know what you're aiming for, think about how you can use your tools (instrumentalists, vocalists, melodies, harmonies, and the odd drummer or two) to get there. Then try it out, and see what it sounds like. Your ears are in charge here.